# Natural norm for the ring $\{a+b\sqrt{2}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb Z \} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces

I am working on showing that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb Z \} $ is an euclidean domain.

There was a similar problem showing that $\{a+b\sqrt{-2}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb Z \} $ was an euclidean domain, but that was easier because for complex numbers one can use the norm $\phi (z) = \bar z \cdot z$.

Does there exist a similar function $\phi$ which is natural to consider for the ring $\{a+b\sqrt{2}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb Z \} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is
$$
a + b \sqrt{2} \mapsto N(a + b \sqrt{2}) = \lvert a^{2} - 2 b^{2} \rvert.
$$
The analogy with the other case you mention is provided by the fact that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ has a single non-trivial automorphism, which is
$$
\sigma : a + b \sqrt{2} \mapsto a - b \sqrt{2},
$$
so that
$$
N(x) = \lvert x \cdot \sigma(x) \rvert,
$$
where you have to take the absolute value, as $a^{2} - 2 b^{2}$ might well be negative.

In the other case you mention, the automorphism is just complex conjugation.